# $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]

Tags: php, file-upload

I used a file upload form to upload files to my server. Then I `echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` but it returns to me a location that does not seem to exist. eg /tmp/phpBparj4 is the output but there is no such file/folder in my /tmp folder. I have also checked for the appropriate permissions for the folder

My actual concern is `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target);` which is not moving the uploaded file to the target location. I have also tried `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"].$file_name,$target);`

Comment: Did you check while the script was running or after?

Comment: I checked after the script finished running

Comment: Its a temp file, so its going to be deleted after the script finishes execution

Comment: then how can i check this folder?

Comment: What's the value of `var_dump($target)`?

Comment: Post some more code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @palintroops
string(61) "/var/www/projects/meme/upload/linked-list-2_04-linked--19.jpg"

Comment: @Musa <form action="<?php $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Upload from Computer</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td> 
   </tr>

Comment: `/var/www/projects/meme/upload/` does this exist and have proper permissions?

Comment: yes it does and permissions are set to 777

Comment: Post your full code, and properly formatted.

Comment: I guess it must be some small syntax error. May be I sholud look more carefully at the code.

Comment: It was a syntax error in the last. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand right but why can't you specify the file folder location? i.e."

```
//set the right path from the server perspective
$article_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

// you should check for the file if it is/ or not already there (something like this)
if (!file_exists($article_file_path ."/your_folder/file_subfolder/". $_FILES["my_file"]["name"]))
      { do something.....


// then make your script upload the file exactly where you want it
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"],          
      $article_file_path ."/your_folder/file_subfolder/".$_FILES["my_file"]["name"]);

// and the download link to the uploaded file would be something like this:
echo "http://". $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files-article/".$_FILES["my_file"]["name"]";
```